# Laravel 5 : Retrieve sent POST data through ajax

Tags: php, laravel

I try to submit a laravel form exactly like this example :

> https://gist.github.com/davestewart/1db1c4b56a85fc46e1f8.

```
$.post('/ajax/post', {payload:'hello'}, onSuccess);
```

When i try to get access the payload string `'hello'` using :

```
$request->get('payload');
```

I get `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get it using `input` :

```
$request->input('payload');
```

And you could first check the developpers console under network tab to make sure that the variable is sent by the post request.

And you could always check the attributes of the request using :

```
dd($request);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Test Your variable inside your javascrip

```
// handlers
        function onGetClick(event)
        {
            // we're not passing any data with the get route, though you can if you want
         console.log(get your variable)
            $.get('/ajax/get', onSuccess);
        }
```

Maybe your variable has no data

Comment: i'am using Post method so here is my data {payload:'hello'}                                                function onPostClick(event)
   {
    // we're passing data with the post route, as this is more normal
    $.post('/ajax/post', {payload:'hello'}, onSuccess);
   }